# How to parse from from streaming excel sheet to python pandas df?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, live

I have an excel sheet with [.xls] format containing live streaming of stock data from a software.
I want to read and process the data from the sheet in python after every 5 seconds.

Python is getting refreshed data only when i manually save the .xls file. It is not automatically getting new data points on running script after 1st time.

Any help?

Comment: How is it supposed to get new data from the file if the changes are not saved?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

```
import threading
import pandas as pd

def main_task():
    threading.Timer(5.0, main_task).start() #Repeats the function main_task every 5 seconds
    df = pd.read_excel("filename.xls") #Reads the excel file
    
main_task() #Calls the function
```

This code will update your pandas DataFrame with the new values every 5 seconds.

Comment: Pls accept this as the best answer if it has helped u. Thx!